Powershell Start-Process with Credential but not obtain elevate privileges
WINDOWS 10 - POWERSHELL 1.0
I can't obtain admin privileges when start an executable with a powershell script, using admin credentials parameters
I've got this snippet of code in a powershell script:
$cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'superBigUser','mypassword'
Start-Process -FilePath "notepad.exe" -Credential $cred -WorkingDirectory "C:\windows\system32"

I'm sure that superBigUser is an administrator and have all privileges but when the notepad run
I open the task manager and in the DETAILS pane in the WITH ELEVATE PRIVILEGES column I see: NO
and in the column of USER NAME I see the correct administrator user: superBigUser
If I use this code instead:
Start-Process -FilePath "notepad.exe" -Verb RunAs

I obtain the correct elevate privileges but I need to enter the correct password manually.
Why I can't obtain the admin privileges with the first code even if I use the correct username and password of an administrator user?
What's wrong? I need an automatic script that don't need typing password.
Thank you for any help.
Fabrizio

you won't be able to bypass UAC. You can try to create a script in the task scheduler

And what the parameter -credential is for?
